# Get product attribute on product list in one query

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute

I figure this part of a code is getting all products for product page

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
        ->addCategoryFilter($this);
```

I need to get available colors only for each product on product list page. So for example if my configurable product consists of 3 simple products with colors: red, green, blue, but simple product with color green is disabled, product with color red is out of stock, how do I show only color "blue".

I would like to do it in single query so it doesn't waste my resources. Is it possible to do some joins on default collection to get that data?

Here is the example of loading few products and under each product's image I would like to show available color.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this script, it works for me.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
              ->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('color', 'blue');
```

Comment: I was thinking more of getting all attributes that are available for each product. Let's say we have 3 colors but only blue is available so it returns blue to me, next product has 4 colors but only 2 available

Comment: @FosAvance Magento already done that code, in `rwd` theme so you dont have to do by your own

Comment: @Murtuza Zabuawala does it loads product by product and then takes its attribute or takes it all together?

Answer (score 1):

First of all this magento theme does not support swatches.

Go to `system->config->general->design->package`

and set `Current Package Name` to `rwd`

so this default `rwd` theme support swatches.